# Указать предложение с придаточным сказуемным

Tags: сказуемые, спп, синтаксис, недопустимая-метка

Укажите предложение с придаточным сказуемным:

> Герой - это тот, кто творит жизнь
> вопреки смерти.
>
> То, чем я горд, тебя пугает.

Мне, кажется, что первое предложение. Как по-вашему?

Comment: Есть такой термин "придаточное сказуемное"?

Comment: Был в прошлом. Похоже на то, что, судя по сообщению telli, и сейчас в каких-то учебниках выделяется. Меня это очень удивило.

===

telli, а по какому учебнику Вы учитесь?

Comment: Если честно в учебнике я не встречала.По книге "Русский язык"(справочные материалы),издание 1987 года.
Этот термин я в тестах встретила,и сама тоже удивилась,даже в интернете дала поиск,и нашла пару статей , с таким заголовком.

Comment: @telli,  сказуемые придаточные предложения соответствуют придаточным определительным. В разных учебниках разный подход. Подробнее об этом можете прочитать в учебнике Русский язык | Е. И. Литневская Русский язык: краткий курс. На Грамоте он есть.

Comment: Это у Бабайцевой такая классификация, в других школьных учебниках такой нет,там даже о местоимённо-определительных до ЕГЭ не говорили, а теперь, похоже, снова не будут, потому что из ЕГЭ такое задание убрали, вид придаточного вообще не определяют.

Comment: Людмила, Литневская упоминает о них.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Герой - это тот, кто творит жизнь
> вопреки смерти.

Это СПП с местоименно-определительным придаточным, в этом случае указательные слова в главной части играют роль подлежащего, сказуемого или дополнения, соответственно различаются подлежащные, сказуемостные и объектные придаточные предложения.

В первом предложении указательное слово является сказуемым, а во втором - подлежащим.